# POSIX-совместимые семейства адресов и протоколы

Tags: сокет, unix, posix

Возможно, я не достаточно внимательно просмотрел стандрат, но я так и не нашел отдельной секции, в которой бы описывались допустимые семейства адресов и протоколы. В описании хедера `netinet/in.h` сказано, что последний должен содержать следующие константы, которые использутся как значения level (!) в функциях getsockopt/setsockopt:

1. IPPROTO_IP
2. IPPROTO_IPv6
3. IPPROTO_ICMP
4. IPPROTO_RAW
5. IPPROTO_TCP
6. IPPROTO_UDP

Могу ли я трактовать это следующим образом - Posix-совместимая система не предполагает использование SCTP протокола, например?

Аналогичная ситуация с семействами адресов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX — это стандарт определяющий необходимый минимум интерфейса ОС. Так что любой список, описанный в нём стоит рассматривать как минимально допустимый набор значений, если не оговорено обратное.

Таким образом содержимое документации `<netinet/in.h>` можно трактовать как «POSIX-совместимая ОС обязана реализовывать перечисленные IP-протоколы»; но это ни как не ограничивает реализацию других протоколов и добавление соответствующих значений в `<netinet/in.h>` любой конкретной ОС.

Comment: Для типов сокетов, например, есть отдельная секция (2.10.6), в которой на данный момент описаны четыре типа сокетов (raw, stream, seqpacket, dgram). И они не трактуются, как "возможные значения аргумента type функции socket". Вот этот момент мне не понятен - почему вышеприведенные типы описаны без привязки к конкретной функции, а о протоколах говорят как о возможных аргументах ф-ий getsockopt/setsockopt.

Comment: @isnullxbh, ИМХО квалифицированно отвечать на вопросы «почему в стандрте написано так, а не иначе» могут только люди принимавшие участие в его написании (кстати на некоторые они отвечают в XRAT), а тут таких скорей всего крайне мало.... в остальном не вижу ничего удивительного — типы сокетов важный системный концепт, заслуживший отдельного упоминания в разделе с основной информацией, а список протоколов, описанный в системном хедере не даёт ни какой информации, зачем эти константы могут быть нужны; так что ссылка на функцию. где они могут быть использованы совсем не лишняя в этом месте...

Comment: Ваш комментарий оказался более убедительным, чем те вещи, о которых гооврится непосредственно в ответе. Спасибо за разъяснения!

Comment: > кстати на некоторые они отвечают в XRAT - ссылкой не поделитесь?

Comment: @isnullxbh, это последний том стандарта: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/contents.html

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку!